# asp.net SERVER_NAME returns wrong domain name

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Can anyone explain me how the asp.net/iis gets SERVER_NAME variable ? 
The problem appears when we change our production domain name. The backend code returns old value by calling the following method `Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]` .
Could it be related to DNS update ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The backend code returns old value by calling the following method Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"]

Generally this [variable returns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

> The server's host name, DNS alias, or IP address as it would appear in self-referencing URLs.

Check

- That the DNS changes have propogated to this server.  Do a reverse DNS lookup on the server itself.  If this is the case, flush the local DNS cache (`ipconfig /flushdns`)
- Make sure the DNS PTR record has been correctly updated
- That the host name isn't set to match the old DNS name