# How do I reset Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, webforms

I have a password reset email going out to users which uses `Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")` to generate a URL for the password reset page. Problem is, the URL of the web application was changed recently, and the old name is still being reflected in the `SERVER_NAME` server variable. How can I reset this so the new, current server name is used? I'd rather not restart the web app in IIS if I don't have to. (I haven't actually stepped through the code; if I'm understanding this correctly, it will work just fine locally because IIS gets refreshed a lot more frequently on my PC than it does on a production web server.) Or am I misunderstanding how server variables work?

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125281/asp-net-server-name-returns-wrong-domain-name

Comment: No, I have not; some of the things suggested in that answer require access to systems which I don't have, but I'll pass it along to someone who can take a look at those things... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In essence from my reading around, your SERVER_NAME may be the name of the windows server itself and not necessarily the DNS name the rest of the world uses to reach that server. HTTP_HOST might be a better bet because it is the contents of the Host http header, which came from what the user typed into their address bar and subsequently what the user's browser passed in order to gain access to the site.

This is particularly helpful for sites that are multi homed, by which I mean one set of code runs eg two websites with different branding/styling, different bindings in IIS (different dns names) but the same underlying code, repeating back to the user what they typed into the browser means they always think they are interacting with the same site